# PDO Transaction not working

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, transactions

I have a PDO Transaction that im trying to run, the first query creates a switch and the second adds information about it to another table. My issue is that for some reason the 1st query doesn't execute correctly but the transaction is committed. (Im using the following PDO Class http://culttt.com/2012/10/01/roll-your-own-pdo-php-class/)

```
try{
    //Insert into required tables
    $db->beginTransaction();
    $db->Query("INSERT INTO firewall (Name)VALUES(:Name)");
    $db->bind(':Name',$Name);
    $db->execute();
    $db->Query("INSERT INTO firewall_switch (Switch_ID, firewall_id,customer_ID)VALUES(:Switch,LAST_INSERT_ID(),:Customer)");
    $db->bind(':Switch',$switch);
    $db->bind(':Customer',$customer);
    $db->execute();
    $db->endTransaction();
}catch(PDOException $e){
    $db->cancelTransaction();
}
```

The following is what gets run in SQL from the logs:

```
6 Query       START TRANSACTION
6 Prepare     [6] INSERT INTO firewall (Name)VALUES(?)
6 Prepare     [7] INSERT INTO firewall_switch (Switch_ID, firewall_id,customer_ID)VALUES(?,LAST_INSERT_ID(),?)
6 Execute     [7] INSERT INTO firewall_switch (Switch_ID, firewall_id,customer_ID)VALUES('2',LAST_INSERT_ID(),'164')
6 Query       COMMIT
```

as you can see the first query never executes but the second does. this particular transaction should have rolled back as there was a duplicate ID which is not allowed.

If there are no duplicates then the transaction seems to complete as expected but im not sure why rollback doesn't work...

EDIT:

DB Class: 
    class Db{

```
    private static $Connection = array();
    public $connection;

    private $dbh;
    private $error;

    private $stmt;

    public static function GetConnection($connection)
    {
        if(!array_key_exists($connection,self::$Connection))
        {
            $className = __CLASS__;
            self::$Connection[$connection] = new $className($connection);
        }
        return self::$Connection[$connection];
    }

    public function __construct($connection){

        global $config;
        //Load Settings


        $this->id = uniqid();
        $this->connection = $connection;

        if(array_key_exists($connection,$config['connections']['database'])){
            $dbConfig = $config['connections']['database'][$connection];

            // Set DSN
            $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $dbConfig['host'] . ';port='.$dbConfig['port'].';dbname=' . $dbConfig['database'];
        }

        // Set options
        $options = array(
            PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT    => true,
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE       => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
        );
        // Create a new PDO instantiate
        try{
            $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $dbConfig['user'], $dbConfig['password'], $options);
        }
        // Catch any errors
        catch(PDOException $e){
            $this->error = $e->getMessage();
            error_log($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
    //Create the SQL Query
    public function query($query){
        $this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
    }
    //Bind SQL Params
    public function bind($param, $value, $type = null){
        if (is_null($type)) {
          switch (true) {
            case is_int($value):
              $type = PDO::PARAM_INT;
              break;
            case is_bool($value):
              $type = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
              break;
            case is_null($value):
              $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
              break;
            default:
              $type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
          }
        }
        $this->stmt->bindValue($param, $value, $type);
    }
    //Execute the SQL
    public function execute($array = NULL){
        if($array == NULL){
            return $this->stmt->execute();
        }else{
            return $this->stmt->execute($array);
        }

    }
    public function resultset(){
        $this->execute();
        return $this->stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
    //Return Single Record
    public function single(){
        $this->execute();
        return $this->stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
    //Count rows in table
    public function rowCount(){
        return $this->stmt->rowCount();
    }
    //Show last ID Inserted into table
    public function lastInsertId(){
        return $this->dbh->lastInsertId();
    }
    //Transactions allows the tracking of multiple record inserts, should one fail all will rollback
    public function beginTransaction(){
        return $this->dbh->beginTransaction();
    }
    public function endTransaction(){
        return $this->dbh->commit();
    }
    public function cancelTransaction(){
        return $this->dbh->rollBack();
    }
    //Debug dumps the info that was contained in a perpared statement
    public function debugDumpParams(){
        return $this->stmt->debugDumpParams();
    }
}
?>
```

DB Structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `firewall` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `Name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Name_UNIQUE` (`Name`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=40 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 

CREATE TABLE `firewall_switch` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `Switch_ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `firewall_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Customer_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`),
  KEY `fk_firewall_switch_Switch1_idx` (`Switch_ID`),
  KEY `fk_firewall_switch_firewall1_idx` (`firewall_id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=59 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: Can you post your `$db` class code and also where you construct it.. the link just shows how to write one, it doesn't give a completed class, . What is the nature of the duplicate check? Can you also show the results of SHOW CREATE TABLE on each of the two tables referenced please.

Comment: Have you set PDO to throw exceptions?  By default it uses the silent error mode, requiring you to explicitly check for errors after every action.  See [Errors and error handling](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php) for more information.

Comment: @Arth Attached my DB Class as well as the DB Structure

Comment: @eggyal i have got this in my DB Class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok So it appears that I have found the resolution, it appears that setting the error mode like this was not working:

```
$options = array(
    PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT    => true,
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE       => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
);
try{
        $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $dbConfig['user'], $dbConfig['password'], $options);
}
```

I have now changed this to:

```
try{
    $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $dbConfig['user'], $dbConfig['password'], array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT    => true));
    $this->dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);    
}
```

Comment: So now you can see why the first insert was never executed... out of interest, why was that?

Comment: my theory is the $this->stmt is being overriden

Comment: Sadly, this misleading answer attracts so many visitors from Google.

Answer (score -1):

By default mysql runs with autocommit enabled so any mysql query will be autocommited despite the begintransaction from pdo.

Make sure you are setting the autocommit off with the mysql command

```
  SET autocommit=0;
```

Also if the mysql backend that you are using (myisam) doesnt support transactions the transaction will not work anyway. (innodb works)

Comment: I realize this is an old comment, but wondered about whether the downvotes were warranted.  In the documentation, it says that autocommit automatically set to 0 by PDO::beginTransaction.  https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.begintransaction.php

Answer (score -1):

Change the first query to be

```
INSERT INTO firewall (Name) VALUES (:Name)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id = LAST_INSERT_ID(id);
```

That way, your subsequent use of `LAST_INSERT_ID` will work whether `:Name" is a dup or not.

Caveat:  It will 'burn' an id each time it is run, so the ids will be consumed faster than desired.  Probably `id` is `INT UNSIGNED` and you are unlikely to hit 4 billion.

(I thought this was discussed in the manual, but I could not find such.  So I added a comment to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html .)